# loading contents of variable in div/modal box

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $loading = $('<img src="loading.gif" alt="loading" class="loading">');

    $('#tire-specs th a').each(function() {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .append($loading.clone());
        var $link = $(this).one('click', function() {
            $dialog
                .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
                .dialog({
                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                    width: 500,
                    height: 300
                });

            $link.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');

                return false;
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

I have got result using ajax in a variable and i want to put that variable content in the modal box. How do i load content of a variable in the modal box? tried several things , but not getting how do i accomplish it. according to me the following code adds the html contents to the modal box. i need it to be modified for loading variable content.

```
$dialog.load($link.attr('href') + ' #content').dialog({
              title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });
```

The original full code is available at 
http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/08/07/creating-dialogs-on-demand/comment-page-1/#comment-10676

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Sorry, missed that the dialog was the part you were most concerned with. See dialog-specific addition at the end.

---

**Original answer**:

To load the HTML from a variable into an element, you use the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function:

```
var markup = "This is <strong>HTML</strong>";
$("#targetElement").html(markup);
```

So if you're loading that markup via ajax, that might be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your.url",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#targetElement").html(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        // ... deal with error ...
    }
});
```

If you're really just grabbing all the content there, that's what the `load` function you used does:

```
$("#targetElement").load("your.url");
```

...but if you want to do something else with it first, use `ajax`.

For instance, let's suppose you're loading some data from the server using JSON notation. Assuming the data looks like this:

```
{
  "foo": "I'm the foo value",
  "bar": "I'm the bar value"
}​​​​​​​​
```

You might do this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://jsbin.com/urebu5",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    // Use the de-serialized object's properties
    // to append HTML to the body
    $("<p>").html(data.foo).appendTo(document.body);
    $("<p>").html(data.bar).appendTo(document.body);
  },
  error: function(xhr, statusText, ex) {
    $("<p>Error running <tt>ajax</tt> call</p>").appendTo(
      document.body
    );
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ipinu4)

---

**Update for dialog**:

Since the jQuery UI dialog just uses elements as the base, the above applies to them as well, here's an example assuming the dialog element has the `id` value "modal-dialog" and is initially hidden (see below for creating the dialog from scratch):

```
function showDialog(content) {
  // Get the dialog element
  var dlgElement = $("#modal-dialog");

  // Update the dialog with the content
  dlgElement.find('p:first').html(content);

  // Show it
  dlgElement.dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
  });
}
```

So using that from our `ajax` call above:

```
// Load our content
$.ajax({
  url: "http://jsbin.com/urebu5",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

    // Show the 'foo' part of the data
    showDialog(data.foo);

  },
  error: function(xhr, statusText, ex) {

    // Show the error
    showDialog("Error running <tt>ajax</tt> call");
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ipinu4/2)

If you want to create the dialog from scratch, just create the elements, and then be sure to remove them when done:

```
function createDialog(title, content) {
  // Create our dialog structure
  return $("<div>")
    .css("display", "none")
    .attr("title", title)
    .html("<p>" + content + "</p>")
    .appendTo(document.body);
}

function showDialog(dlg, destroy) {
  var opts = {
    height: 140,
    modal: true
  };
  if (destroy) {
    opts.close = function(event, ui) {
      $(this).remove();
    };
  }
  dlg.dialog(opts);
}
```

Use:

```
// Load our content
$.ajax({
  url: "http://jsbin.com/urebu5",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

    // Create a dialog using 'foo' part of the data
    var dlg = createDialog("Foo Data", data.foo);

    // Show it
    showDialog(dlg, true);

  },
  error: function(xhr, statusText, ex) {

    // Create a dialog using 'foo' part of the data
    var dlg = createDialog(
      "Foo Data - Error",
      "Error running <tt>ajax</tt> call"
    );

    // Show it
    showDialog(dlg, true);

  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ipinu4/7)