# jQuery.get onClick with other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Previously I asked about how I could call separate values from a text file without using php ( [Include .txt content WITHOUT server side lang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601109/include-txt-content-without-server-side-lang) ), and with some of your help I solved the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.get('db.txt', function(data) {
    $('#db').html(data);
     var element = $("#db").text().split("|"); 
     $('#1').text(element[1]);
     $('#3').text(element[3]);
   });
  </script>

  <span id="db" style="display:none;"></span>

  <span id="1"></span>
  <span id="3"></span>
```

If my text file looks like this Name1 | Number1 | Name2 | Number2 | it will display:

Number 1 Number 2

Works great, except I have ONE little problem left.

Before, when I used php, I had an OnClick function that looked like this:

```
onClick="simpleCart.add('name=Productname', 'price=<?php echo ''.$field[$loop][1].''; ?>','quantity=1');
```

The price was echoed from the database with php, but now I can't use any server side language any more. `<span id="1"></span>` gets the same value as `<?php echo ''.$field[$loop][1].''; ?>` does, I just don't know how to write it in the OnClick function? I need the span value to be equal the price.

Hope you can help me out here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('span#1').click(function() {
     /* your code like
     simpleCart.add('name=Productname', 'price=' + $('span#1').text(),'quantity=1');
    */
});
```

or

```
$('span#1').bind('click', function() {
    /* your code like
     simpleCart.add('name=Productname', 'price=' + $('span#1').text(),'quantity=1');
    */
});
```

check jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @jessifelt glad to hear that. but please google it before you ask something. whatever you want to do, somebody has done it before.